# "To do back that far" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

I ran into an expression *"to do back that far"* and I couldn't understand the meaning from the context. I tried to find similar ones, but it seems that such expressions are not very common. So, I've found only one example:

> "These songs, they're like mystery stories, the kind that Shakespeare saw when he was growing up. I think you could trace what I **do back that far**. They were on the fringes then, and I think they're on the fringes now. And they sound like they've been on the hard ground."

What does it really mean?

P.S. 
Another example:

> He's absolutely out there, you know, with his theories. Some of them **do**
>   **back far** but this deuterium thing that he's nailed at the moment
>   really really does interest me.

Comment: What context? That is  precisely what we need to explain what it means to you. However, I doubt that |**to** do back that far| makes sense. Here we have: To trace something back that far. The previous context in the conversation is needed.

Comment: @Lambie I've added context just now.

Comment: "Some of them do back far" doesn't make sense to me.  I wonder if that was a transcription error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "These songs, they're like mystery stories, the kind that Shakespeare
>   saw when he was growing up. I think you could trace what I do back
>   that far. They were on the fringes then, and I think they're on the
>   fringes now. And they sound like they've been on the hard ground."

The use of "back that far" here refers to Shakespeare's time.

Here is the parse: I think you can trace||what I do||back that far [to Shakespeare's time.]

So, the writer is saying that he writes songs **that** can be traced **back  that far**. that far = to the time of Shakespeare.

In speaking, we often use this kind of **shortened phrasing** to refer back to something that has already been said that.

The second sentence is "off" somehow:

"He's absolutely out there, you know, with his theories. **Some of them do back far** but this deuterium thing that he's nailed at the moment really really does interest me."

He might have meant: **go** back far [go back a long way??] But, as cited, it makes no sense.

Comment: The second sentence was actually the first I ran into. All I could find similar was that about songs. So, if he really meant "go" I can't understand it anyway. What could it mean that "his theories go back a long way..."? That they are related to something that was already known in the past?

Comment: Or that "he gets this far" in his theories?

Comment: And about *"deuterium thing"* - is it a figurative meaning like something extraordinary?

Comment: To go back a long way=to be old historically or in time. Newton's theories go back a long way=are old, go back in time. I have no  idea about the deuterium thing. Obviously, I am not a chemist. To get this far: to get to this point. Please note: ***this and that*** are very often used in English to refer to earlier points in a conversation or in remarks.  You and I have gotten this far [up to this point] in our discussion.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation! If the conversation isn't about chemistry can that mean *"amazing thing"* or something like that?

Comment: @Sergey Not as far as I am aware. I know of no expression in English with that. Bear in mind, again, that in spoken language, you can take any noun and add thing like this example, to mean a topic or subject: that [noun] thing. Meaning: the topic of [noun] under discussion.